# Help needed in booting Ubuntu after failed switch from Elementary OS

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub

Basically, I tried to switch from Elementary OS to Ubuntu, but it didn't work. Now, I can't boot into either of them.

When I try to boot into Ubuntu, it says it can't locate the ISO file. Additionally, I can't see my bootable USB stick as an option to boot.

What options do I have now? I simply want Ubuntu to boot. Grub `ls` gives me `hd0`, `proc`, `(hd0,gpt1)`, `(hd0,gpt2)`, but I don't know which of these is my USB stick or how to boot from it.

Comment: Neither is your USB stick. How exactly did you *tried to switch from Elementary OS to Ubuntu*? Please [edit] the question and describe exactly what you did. Also post hardware specifications. Then it may be possible to understand what happened and provide some help. That said it seems you need to understand the boot process (UEFI mode for any PC from ~2012 or newer) and what it entails.

Comment: Try `ls (hd0,gpt1)/` and `ls (hd0,gpt1)/` Then you will get information about the content of your partition. Then the `linux` command followed by the linux kernel path may load a kernel (you will have to add `root=/dev/sdaX ro` where X is 1 or 2 depends of the root partition. `initrd` can be used to load your initrd.img file... and `boot`... boot. You can edit the question and put what you see.